# Public service to convert bmp/gif/png/etc to jpg?

Tags: javascript, web-services, api, image-conversion

Is there any public service which I can use to convert any of the common image formats (gif, png, bmp, tga, etc) to a jpg?  I'm looking for something I can use from within javascript, sending the image to whereever, then getting back a jpg I can use.

I am not looking for something manual, where I can go to http://foo.bar.com, manually upload the image, then manually save the returned jpg.  I'm looking for something I can use as an actual web service remotely.

Comment: If you already have access to the file in JS, there might be a way to do it locally, such as a JavaScript plugin/script. This would also remove the lengthy latency involved with the transfer.

Comment: It's not sensible for who host web service as you want, against bandwith

Comment: Assume you're in a "drag images into this box, then do something with those images, then eventually submit and they'll be uploaded" situation, or something along the same lines; for example gmail's attach file, if you wanted to have it convert all images to jpg.  There, that latency is essentially invisible to the user, as it's all background.  Compare that to what Dan suggests, where that is not a simple js lib function to do the conversion, nor is it really economical in terms of bytes of js loaded and executed user-end; that's not a low-cpu-use script for the user's computer to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at [api.online-convert.com](http://api.online-convert.com/) - it's free but you have to put a back-link to their service somewhere on your website.

hope this helps!

Comment: Just a followup, it's not a 100% perfect solution; they limit you to 30 conversions/day with a key, rather than ip-limiting or something like that which would be more useful for (in my case) a greasemonkey script that many people will use.